# AngularJS IE8 - Not loading application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I followed the guidelines on AngularJS.org as much as possible and my app is not running on IE8.
I'm using every poly fill I can but it just will not start. Specifically ES5 Shim and Sham and the HTML5 shim..

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="chm" >
```

I get the error that AngularJS cannot instantiate module named chm because it was not included. It works in every version of IE past 8 and all other browsers. What am I doing wrong for ie8? Please help. I am using version 1.2.7.
I also tried manually bootstrapping the application by placing it at the bottom of the code with

```
<script>angular.bootstrap(document, ['chm']);</script>
<script>
```

More information -- It appears to have been a bug in my code, kind of.

It didn't like a particular controllers JS which included a jqlite command

```
    this.class =
```

Comment: a guess: can it work without id="ng-app" ?

Comment: I think it should be `ng-app="chm"`. `ng-app` is a directive, not an ID. Check the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)...

Comment: How did you define the module?

Comment: @War10ck http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Says you have to include id="ng-app"

Comment: @plalx 
    var chm = angular.module('chm',[]);

Comment: @PatrickCauley I stand corrected. My apologies buddy.

Comment: Not your fault..I'm at a complete loss at the moment. I followed the documentation to a T and now my app won't work and IE8 support is a must. Of course I have been building this for nearly 4 months no and have only today tested it in ie8 because everything else has worked swimmingly. Obviosuly..I'm at fault here but damn it sucks...

Comment: Is this fixed since you removed the this.class or are you still looking for an answer?